# Define two path test for non-existence of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Can someone help me to solve this question and explain it extensively

(Means step by step solution/approach):

Define two path test for non-existence of a limit and show that $$f(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt3x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$$ is continuous at $(0, 0).$

This is how I have done, whether thats correct ?

Path 1: y = 0

Along this path, f(x,y) = 0 for all x. Therefore, the limit of f(x,y) as (x,y) approaches (0,0) along this path is 0.

Path 2: y = mx

Along this path, we have:

f(x,y) = sqrt(3)x^2y^2 / (x^2 + y^2)
= sqrt(3)x^2(mx)^2 / (x^2 + (mx)^2)
= sqrt(3)x^4m^2 / (x^2 + x^2m^2)
= sqrt(3)x^2m^2

Therefore, the limit of f(x,y) as (x,y) approaches (0,0) along this path is 0.

Since the limits along the two paths are different, Hence, f(x,y) is not continuous at (0,0).

Comment: Are you sure limit doesn't exist? What is your work on it so far?

Comment: As a first step polar coordinates can be a good tool to check for the limit..

Comment: Or also by $(x-y)^2\ge 0 \implies |xy| \le \frac{x^2+y^2}2$ and $x^2y^2=|xy||xy|$

Comment: $0$ and $0$ are different?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/845287/505767

Comment: The function is not continuous at (0,0) because is not defined there. However the limit towards (0,0) exists and is 0.

Comment: @WindSoul And we can eliminate the discontinuity setting $f(0,0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

One way we might consider whether a limit of multivariable limit exists is to define $y$ to be a function of x and evaluate the single variable limit.

However, this is not conclusive.  It is possible for a function to have a limit that evaluates to $a$ following one path, and $b$ when following another.  If the limit exists, it must be the same along all paths.  So, the 2 pathed approach cannot prove the existence of a limit, but it can prove non-existence.

If the limit does not exist, the function is not continuous.

Find two functions that will return different values when you evaluate the limit.  I would start with $y=x$ and then $y = mx,$ but you might need to be more creative.